# I don't understand TYPO3's image management, Images are not properly sized

Tags: image, typo3, size, element

I am new in TYPO3, and I am trying something simple, add an image.
Iam doing the following:

1. I added Content Element "Text & Images"
2. In the tab "Images" i uploaded an image 1920 x 262
3. Save

The image loaded is the resolution 600 x 81, i don't understan why.
In the properties i try set 1920 in the field width but same.

In the future i want to know how establish the srcset but first the simple.
(sorry my english)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to confuse you but there are some rules applied to the maximum size which date back to those days where 600 was already quite large.

the following typoscript constants are relevant:

```
styles.content {
  maxW = 600
  maxWInText = 300
}
```

Depending on the selected value of the field *Position and Alignment*, one of those 2 applies. So If e.g. "in text, right" is selected, the maximum width is 300.

As a solution you can override the constants to same values which fit more properly.

---

Most people don't use the default content elements anymore and create custom ones using extensions like [mask](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/) or [dce](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/dce/) or without any 3rd party code.